# Why there is a LinkTarget key in Manifest.mbdb file of iOS backup files?

Tags: ios, iphone, jailbreak

I am learning about p0sixSpwn jailbreak now; I'm just find that the first step of the jailbreak is to create a symlink using the backup protocol;

By reading some docs I found that there is a "LinkTarget" key in the Manifest.mbdb file, which is used to store the directory information of the backup files; We can use this key to create symlink in backup;

But I want to know what should it was designed to to do; I can't find any C structure containg the key "LinkTarget".